# Deploying .NET Core 2.1 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core web application, and what happens is that I'm constantly getting a 500 server error

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Regardless of what I put into the file system folder (I tried 3 different .NET Core web apps), there's always this error. I tried standard Visual Studio "Hello world" application - same thing. Logs are not created, this is the sample entry from the web.config file being used:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestAppMin.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

I manually created logs/stdout folder and changed IIS app pool rights to it - read/write.

IIS pool is configured as "No managed code" and "Integrated" pipeline.

I tried debug and release mode - no avail. I changed exception handling to custom  in Startup.cs - still 500 error.

Latest .NET Core SDK is installed on the server.

If I manually create default.htm file, it's being displayed properly.

Can someone please advise me what am I doing wrong? Is there a way to diagnose that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have enabled AspNetCore Module in IIS under Handler Mappings ? I got it on first position.

Comment: When click on that (and actually on most of the icons in IIS in that web site) it says:

There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

Filename: \\?\C:\inetpub\mywebsite\web.config
Error:

Comment: Actually, if I click on Handler Mappings under the server branch (not the web site), there's no AspNetCore module there. What do I do? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, .NET Core runtime was not installed. Thanks for pointing out!